Howto declare a variable that initializes to another in a macro in C
I have an embedded device that I am storing some constant information in Flash. I want a macro that allows me to easily declare a copy of it in RAM. So I made one that looks like this:
#if defined(ENABLE_RAM_COPY)
    #define DATA_DEF(TYPE, NAME, VAL)   \
    const TYPE NAME = VAL;              \
    TYPE RAM_##NAME = NAME;             \
    TYPE get_##NAME(void) {             \
        return RAM_##NAME;              \
    }
#else
    #define DATA_DEF(TYPE, NAME, VAL)   \
        const TYPE NAME = VAL;          \
        TYPE get_##NAME(void) {         \
            return NAME;                \
        }
#endif

In my source, this let's me declare data and then based on the ENABLE_RAM_COPY definition, read it from Flash or RAM.
#define ENABLE_RAM_COPY
DATA_DEF(uint8_t, MYDATA, 10)

My problem is, if you see from the macro definition, I want the RAM copy to be initialized to whatever is in Flash. That is not what I'm actually seeing, though.
If I build and load this source I see both the Flash and RAM memory as 0x0A. If I then change the Flash to 0xA5 and restart. The RAM copy stays at 0x0A.
If I inspect the assembly for the macro expansion at runtime, it is clearly not referencing Flash at all:


My problem is, if you see from the macro definition, I want the RAM copy to be initialized to whatever is in Flash. - this sounds like what we usually do with the .data segment on "ROM-able" FW. The initialized data is flashed as part of the firmware image, and the startup code is copying to the target address in the RAM. Again, it is done in the startup code, early, before main. It also does not care about types whatsoever, just a blind section copy

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but if main needs access to both the information in flash, and the copy in RAM, then define another uninitialized variable in RAM and do a memcpy.

Is your code running from flash, or are you loading it into RAM from the debugger?

@IanAbbott the code is loaded to RAM. I understand I could setup a memcpy, but I am trying to understand why RAM_MYDATA = MYDATA is not doing an equivalent operation. Where is the data be loaded into RAM_MYDATA coming from?

IMO XY problem. What is the MCU?

FYI (and completely tangentially) — ISO/IEC 9899:2024 was published in late October 2024.  (I updated the C tag info and C tag wiki with the new information.)  The price at ISO is 216 CHF (about 258.40 USD).  The ANSI Web Store still has the 2018 standard (and not the 2024 standard) at midday today — it will become unavailable as soon as it has created the ANSI version of the 2024 standard.  The 2018 standard costs $278, so the 2024 standard will probably cost about the same and is comparable to the cost direct from ISO.

uint8_t RAM_MYDATA = MYDATA; is not even a standard C initialization if RAM_MYDATA is statically allocated, because MYDATA is a non-modifiable variable, not a "constant expression". But the C standard allows implementations to "accept other forms of constant expressions", so perhaps your compiler accepts the use of a const qualified value as a constant expression.

@JonathanLeffler That's good news. Some national standards bodies were hinting at 2025 as the publication date, but perhaps that's for republication by the national bodies.

Assuming you are relying on a compiler extension that allows you to use a const-qualified variable value (MYDATA) as an initializer for another statically defined, and modifiable variable (RAM_MYDATA), the compiler "knows" the value of the MYDATA at the time of compilation, and can use that value as the initial value of RAM_MYDATA. This does imply that the generated code has to copy MYDATA to RAM_MYDATA at run time. It can initialize RAM_DATA in the same way as other statically defined, modifiable variables, by copying from the section's "load address" to its real address.

Conditional compilation directives are evaluated at the point where they are encountered.  In your case, this means that whatever definition, if any, ENABLE_RAM_COPY already has at the point where the #if defined(ENABLE_RAM_COPY) directive appears is the one that controls which definition of DATA_DEF is selected.  (re)defining ENABLE_RAM_COPY later does not affect the already chosen definition of DATA_DEF.
There are ways that you could do a per-item selection of whether to fetch the data from RAM or from flash.  You're already using extra code at the point of item definition to select the alternative, so the easiest way, and certainly among the clearest, would be to have different macros for the two alternatives.  For example,
#define DATA_DEF_RAM(TYPE, NAME, VAL)   \
const TYPE NAME = VAL;              \
TYPE RAM_##NAME = NAME;             \
TYPE get_##NAME(void) {             \
    return RAM_##NAME;              \
}

#define DATA_DEF_FLASH(TYPE, NAME, VAL)   \
const TYPE NAME = VAL;              \
TYPE get_##NAME(void) {             \
    return NAME;                    \
}

Then, instead of
// ORIGINAL
#define ENABLE_RAM_COPY
DATA_DEF(uint8_t, MYDATA, 10)

you would do
// REVISED
DATA_DEF_RAM(uint8_t, MYDATA, 10)

.  Or the alternative would be
// REVISED
DATA_DEF_FLASH(uint8_t, MYDATA, 10)

That's both simpler and clearer on every side.

I'll test this in a bit once I'm back in front of my computer. The objective of the ENABLE_RAM_COPY directive wasn't for an individual item, but a .c file level control of the data items stored in RAM. If I understand your comment correctly though, you're saying the wrong definition of DATA_DEF is being used. I'm not sure if that's true based on the assembly screenshot from runtime. It's accessing RAM for the data. That data just wasn't initialized from Flash?

Then the question is misleading, @linsek, but this answer still explains the issue with your original code.  If you want a file-scoped switch then your original code can work. You just need to ensure that the definition of ENABLE_RAM_COPY appears before the conditional compilation directive that depends on it.  At the very top of the file tends to be good.

sorry, John. I'm not sure I follow why the question is misleading. But I did change the setup to completely remove the ENABLE_RAM_COPY directive and defined a RAM and FLASH version of the macro as you indiciated. There was no functional change to the source generated. The RAM_ version of the data is still not initialized to the data from flash as I'd expect.

@linsek, the question is misleading because it shows the ENABLE_RAM_COPY macro being defined at the point where you use the DATA_DEF macro, not where you define DATA_DEF.  Additionally, it seems, the question is misleading inasmuch as it can be taken to assert that the code generated by one of the versions of the macro actually does what you want.  If you're not sure what code you need to generate, then you need to determine that first.  Until then, writing a macro for it is way premature.

What this code does is actually to create 2 tables in flash and 1 in RAM. One manually declared table in flash and a second unnamed table in flash .rodata, which is used solely for the purpose of initializing the RAM table, which happens during .data initialization. You don't get any coupling between the two flash tables and you store the same data twice in flash for nothing gained.
Instead you should declare the flash array as an object of its own and memcpy it down into RAM manually, into an array of the same size as the one in flash. This takes the same time as .data initialization but happens when you like it to happen and not inside the "CRT" before main() is called.
Alternatively you could have a volatile array of pointers in RAM pointing into the flash array, but that gives a bit slower access time.
Which method that is best depends on your purpose with this RAM array.

sorry, I am not sure I follow. Looking at my map file I see the definition in the flash segment, the RAM_ definition in the .data segment, and the function to access in the .text segment. I don't see any unnamed tables in .rodata. I know I could setup a memcpy on startup to copy everything from flash to RAM, but I'm trying to understand why the RAM_ isn't being set properly based on this macro definition. The expansion should be RAM_MYDATA = MYDATA.

@linsek It could be placed in .text as well I guess, it's compiler/linker-specific. The point is that any RAM variable with static storage duration which you initialize will end up with a flash copy containing the default values. If you want to know exactly what's going on, you can peek into the CRT start-up code.


My problem is, if you see from the macro definition, I want the RAM copy to be initialized to whatever is in Flash. That is not what I'm actually seeing, though.

The RAM copy (RAM_##NAME) is initialized only at compile-time, not at runtime. Therefore, even if you change the Flash value (NAME) after the program has been loaded, the RAM copy won’t automatically update because the assignment TYPE RAM_##NAME = NAME.
If you want to make the RAM copy update to the Flash value at runtime, you probably need to add code that explicitly updates RAM_##NAME from NAME when the program initializes.
#include <stdint.h>

#define ENABLE_RAM_COPY

#if defined(ENABLE_RAM_COPY)
    #define DATA_DEF(TYPE, NAME, VAL)        \
        const TYPE NAME = VAL;               \
        TYPE RAM_##NAME;                     \
        TYPE get_##NAME(void) {              \
            return RAM_##NAME;               \
        }                                    \
        void init_##NAME(void) {             \
            RAM_##NAME = NAME;               \
        }
#else
    #define DATA_DEF(TYPE, NAME, VAL)        \
        const TYPE NAME = VAL;               \
        TYPE get_##NAME(void) {              \
            return NAME;                     \
        }
#endif

DATA_DEF(uint8_t, MYDATA, 10)

void init_ram_copies(void) {
    // Copy Flash value to RAM
    #ifdef ENABLE_RAM_COPY 
        init_MYDATA();  
    #endif
}

int main(void) {
    // Initialize RAM copies
    init_ram_copies();

    return 0;
}

